# Is there a way to size a box as a perfect square based on its content in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create perfect square box with some text inside. I'm trying to make the box fit-to-content but keep aspectRatio of 1f, but that makes it size to its maximum constraints and not minimum constraints.

**All in all I want the box to be minimum 24x24, if content is bigger, then fit box to content.**

Here's some example which does not work:

*P.S the dark grey box is 24x24, just as reference.*

```
@Composable
fun SquareBox(
  text: String,
) {
  Box(
    modifier = Modifier
      .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
      .background(Color.Gray)
      .defaultMinSize(24.dp, 24.dp)
   // .sizeIn(minWidth = 24.dp, minHeight = 24.dp, maxWidth = 48.dp, maxHeight = 48.dp)
      .aspectRatio(1f),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
  ) {
    Text(
      text = text,
      color = Color.White,
      maxLines = 1,
      overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
      modifier = Modifier
    )
  }
}
```

This works as expected, which is; not a perfect square. 
It fits to content but minimum 24 dp.

```
 .defaultMinSize(24.dp, 24.dp)
```

[Preview just defaultMinsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmHdZ.png)

This always sizes to max width of screen it looks like.
I would have expected this to work though ;(
The 0 box would be 24x24 and the 2396 would be something like 32x32.

```
.defaultMinSize(24.dp, 24.dp)
.aspectRatio(1f)
```

[Preview defaultMinSize + aspectRatio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6aEM.png)

This always sizes to 48x48 even if it doesn't have to.

```
.sizeIn(minWidth = 24.dp, minHeight = 24.dp, maxWidth = 48.dp, maxHeight = 48.dp)
.aspectRatio(1f)
```

[Preview sizeIn + aspectRatio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66M09.png)

Comment: So specify default MaxSize equal to what you return and not some specific sizes, you can also specify that defaultMaxSize will be equal to something but not more than such and such sizes.

Comment: @BuratinoApps excuse me, what? Can you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

#### I've just finished [the article about this exact problem](https://medium.com/@mmolosays/square-size-in-jetpack-compose-2d66457a83ea)

Here's the code for custom layout modifier:

```kotlin
@Stable
fun Modifier.squareSize(
    position: Float = 0.5f,
): Modifier =
    layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val constraintsSize = min(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight)
        val squareConstraints = constraints.copy(
            maxWidth = constraintsSize,
            maxHeight = constraintsSize,
        )

        val placeable = measurable.measure(squareConstraints)
        val size = max(placeable.width, placeable.height)

        layout(width = size, height = size) {
            val x = ((size - placeable.width) * position).toInt()
            val y = ((size - placeable.height) * position).toInt()
            placeable.placeRelative(x, y)
        }
    }
```

Used in your case like this:

```kotlin
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Green) // outer box
        .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 60.dp, minHeight = 60.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
) {
    Text(
        text = "9",
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue) // square
            .squareSize(position = 0.5f)
            .background(Color.Magenta), // text itself
    )
}
```

[image]

If you increase `fontSize` so that `Text()` is bigger than `defaultMinSize`, then the square size will be based on text size.
Here's the result with `fontSize = 120.sp`:
[image]